# Controlling a .mov (<object>) file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, movie, .mov

So my question is **how do I start a movie with a call to a javascript / jquery function?**

Background:

I have an object in my html that embeds is a .mov file like so:

```
<object CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" width="100%" height="100%" class="movie1" id="movie1ie">
                <param name="src" value="movies/test.mov">
                <param name="autoplay" value="false">
                <param name="loop" value="false">
                <param name="controller" value="false">
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="video/quicktime" data="movies/test.mov" width="100%" height="100%" class="movie1" id="movie1">
                    <param name="autoplay" value="false">
                    <param name="loop" value="false">
                    <param name="controller" value="false">
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
```

And it seems to be okay, until I want to play the movie with a call to javascript. I am using jQuery so I tried this from within a function:

```
function startMovie(whom){
    var playIt = 'movie'+ whom;
    $('#' + playIt).get(0).play();
}
//and call the function
startMovie(1);
```

But then I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'play'
```

Weird, but I'm no jQuery ninja so I tried to call it using good ole javascript:

```
function startMovie(1){
    var playIt = 'movie'+ whom;
    document.getElementById(playIt).Play();
}
```

But now I get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
```

Which is very wierd, since if I put the following into my console the movie will start playing without errors:

```
document.getElementById('movie1').Play()
```

FWIW I am using Chrome on a Mac and the files are running on the local machine (no server).

Comment: I found your question by google  - I have an similar problem. Did you found any solutions?

Comment: Btw.: If anyone has an equal problem and no answer: my solution was checking the syntax of the embedded document. If there is an error, for example the video-source does not exist, than the QT player initialization is not correct(even everything looks fine). In this case, the `Play()` method is not initialized, what result in `Error calling method on NPObject. `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function startMovie(whom){
    var playIt = 'movie'+ whom;
    document.getElementById(playIt).Play();
}
startMovie('1');
```

Try that.

Comment: I had a typo in my question, My function looks like that already, but I call the function with `startMovie(1);` number not a string, would that make a diff?

Comment: There is a possibility. Before the line with `.Play` put `console.log(document.getElementById(playIt));` and see what it returns.

Comment: It returns: `<object type="video/quicktime" data="Welcome to FONA.mov" width="100%" height="100%" class="movie2" id="movie2" style="">
      <param name="autoplay" value="false">
      <param name="loop" value="false">
      <param name="controller" value="false">
     </object>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZcLb/1/ (Not sure about the linking to the dropbox hosted .mov file, but the same errors were popping up)